# Adding hidden global attribute to div

Tags: jquery, html

Pretty simple thing but I can't seem to get it working, nor can I find a post on how to do this.

I'm creating a div using

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

and then trying to set the global attribute of 'hidden' on the div like so

```
div.setAttribute('hidden', '');
```

When I check the source my div doesn't have the hidden attribute.

If I try this with `disabled` instead of `hidden`, it works fine.

All I want is that when the div is created, it starts as hidden so I can then un-hide it when appropriate, like so

```
<div hidden> <!-- Rest of content --> </div>
```

I realize there are other ways of doing this but I'm wondering why this way doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: In my case the code is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it works. Make sure that you're not overwriting code.
Anyway, you can use jQuery [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```js
var div = $('<div/>').prop('hidden', true);
$('body').append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

</body>
```